# Unable to ssh into QNX 6.5.0 VirtualBox session

Tags: ssh, qnx

I've reinstalled the QNX RTOS 6.5.0 on virtualbox of which I was able to ssh into using the following command: `ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 3022`. The network settings inside my VirtualBox environment is set to NAT, and port forwarding set to:

[image: QNX VirtualBox Network settings]

When attempting to connect with `-vvv` flags:

```
$ ssh -vvv root@127.0.0.1 -p 3022
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/main/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "127.0.0.1" port 3022
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 3022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/main/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/main/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/main/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/main/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/main/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/main/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/main/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/main/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

On QNX I have the following options modified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
Subsystem sftpd /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

I am also able to ssh into my laptop via the vm, however not the other way around. I also tried ssh'ing into my laptop which works, then ssh'ing back into the vm in the same vm session and am presented with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The solution was to generate new rsa and dsa keys with:

```
random -t
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key -b 1024
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

and then add sshd to the `/etc/group` list: `sshd:x:6:root`

then re-run sshd: `/usr/sbin/sshd`

source: [How do you install an ssh server on qnx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150737/how-do-you-install-an-ssh-server-on-qnx)

To extend on the above sourced solution, I found that on reboot I was no longer able to ssh into the VM. This was solved by going into `/etc/rc.d/` and adding the line `/usr/sbin/sshd` to the `rc.local` file.